# How to sign the Hash (Pdf files hash value) using Digital Signature in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, digital-signature, sha256, pfx

**My requirement in short** - Sign the 'Pdf document's Hash' using 'Digital Signature' with a .pfx certificate and return the 'signed hash' (signed pdf)

**1.** I have 1 pdf in my local patch(in Xcode), and that pdf contains a 'rectangular box' for digital signing

**2.** Then I am generating SHA256 Hash from the pdf document.

- Here I am converting pdf into base64 string and using the following function I am generating SHA256 Hash

```
let samplePdfBase64String = "JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQoNCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8D.....T0YNCg=="

guard let data = samplePdfBase64String.data(using: .utf8) else { return }

let digest = SHA256.hash(data: data)
print(digest.hexStr) // 3DAD8D6CD86B405DCB06FE6E546C8792CE23DCF67B9772E11C14292D32925C7B

let pdfsHashValue =  digest.hexStr
```

I am using following extension

```
extension Digest { //It will gnerate hash value
    var bytes: [UInt8] { Array(makeIterator()) }
    var data: Data { Data(bytes) }

    var hexStr: String {
        bytes.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

**3.** Now I need to sign the Hash using the pfx file. (Sign Hash using Digital Signing)

From step 2, already I generated hash value `( pdfsHashValue = "3DAD8D6CD86B405DCB06FE6E546C8792CE23DCF67B9772E11C14292D32925C7B" )`

I have a valid .pfx file and added it into Xcode.

```
let pfxFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fred", ofType: "pfx")
```

**4.** Now I need to add a signature to this hash (pdf's hash). A signature can contain details like the Name of the signer, location, Reason..etc

Using a combination of **1.** some hashing algorithms ex. SHA256, **2.** pfx certificate and its password, **3.** A hash value (pdf's hash)

- it should process and return the signed hash (signed pdf's hash).
- That digital signature should pad//append to signed hash

**5. final output** - it should return a signed hash (signed pdf)

In short,
generate SHA256 hash from pdf file -> Sign the Hash using Digital Certificate -> Pad nack the Signed Hash -> return Signed hash/pdf.

Can someone help me to achieve this? I tried Foxit SDK, PSPdfkit library - not helped me because they are using direct pdf for signing.